# SKVideoNode frame rate

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, avplayer, skvideonode

Basically SKVideoNode will not respect AVPlayer's rate.

By default, SKVideoNode has no way of controlling playback rate. However, the SKVideoNode can be initialized with an AVPlayer (which itself contains an AVPlayerItem). This AVPlayer has a property rate which can vary from 0 to 2 (1 is normal speed). There is also the method setRate:time:atHostTime:.

So the rate doesn't work. Have you had the same problem?.
If there is no way to resolve this? is there another way to play a video and change the frame rate in a SKScene?

```
func setupVideo() {
    // play video
    let urlStr = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sample", ofType: "mp4")
    let url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: urlStr!)

    player = AVPlayer(URL: url)

    videoNode = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player!)
    videoNode?.position = CGPointMake(frame.size.width/2, frame.size.height/2)
    videoNode?.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
    videoNode?.zPosition = 1
    addChild(videoNode!)

    player!.rate = 0.25
    videoNode!.play()


}
```

It doesn't matter where I add player!.rate = 0.25, it never changes.

Comment: can you show some code or a project ?

Comment: sure @RhythmicFistman http://collabedit.com/f4a7j

Comment: did you try changing the speed of the node?

Comment: No @Knight0fDragon, how can I do that?

Comment: `.speed` on your node lol

Comment: lol. No, it doesn't work changing the speed

Comment: which iOS version?

Answer (score 2):

-- UPDATE
This was an Apple API issue, it was fixed in iOS 10 version.